# iOS SpriteKit collision with screen edges not working

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a collision between an SKShapeNode instance and the edges of the screen but for some reason the ShapeNode still goes beyond the limits of the screen. I have implemented code that I believe should take care of the collision but I am new to SpriteKit so I am not entirely sure. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  SpriteKitTest
//
//  Created by 580380 on 3/10/16.
//  Copyright (c) 2016 580380. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class GameScene: SKScene {

    //MARK: - Global variables
    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    var circleNode = SKShapeNode()
    var destX : CGFloat = 0.0
    var destY : CGFloat = 0.0

    enum Collision :UInt32 {
        case ball = 1
        case wall = 2
    }
    //MARK: - Sprite kit functionality
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        createCircleNode()
        moveCircleNode()
        self.addChild(circleNode)
    }

    //Setup and configuring the SKShapeNode object
    private func createCircleNode() {
        circleNode.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)), radius: 20, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(2*M_PI), clockwise: true).CGPath
        circleNode.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
        circleNode.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        circleNode.lineWidth = 1
    }

    private func moveCircleNode() {
        circleNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
        circleNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        circleNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable {
            motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
            motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), withHandler: { (data, error) -> Void in
                self.destX = self.circleNode.position.x + CGFloat(data!.acceleration.x*100)
                self.destY = self.circleNode.position.y + CGFloat(data!.acceleration.y*200)
            })
        }
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
        self.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
        self.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = Collision.wall.rawValue
        self.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = Collision.ball.rawValue
    }

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        let destXAction = SKAction.moveToX(destX, duration: 0.1)
        let destYAction = SKAction.moveToY(destY, duration: 0.1)
        self.circleNode.runAction(destXAction)
        self.circleNode.runAction(destYAction)
    }
}
```

Any idea where I could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here I will assume is that the Game Scene never actually gets its size set.

In your `GameViewController` add the line `scene.size = skView.bounds.size` under `let skView = self.view as! SKView`.

This will set the size of your scene correctly, so now your ball should collide with your screen edge.... however when you set your `circleNode` path, the way you implemented it with offset your circle by half the size of the screen.

If you want your circle to appear in the middle of the screen, a better solution would be to have `circleNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 20)` instead of `circleNode.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)), radius: 20, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(2*M_PI), clockwise: true).CGPath`. Then set it to be in the center with `circleNode.position = CGPointMake(frame.width/2, frame.height/2)`.

This should solve your issue as a whole, however something you may notice is that the ball may disappear through the edge the screen. To fix this, change your update method to something like this

```
func clamp(value: CGFloat, min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    if value > max {
        return max
    }
    if value < min {
        return min
    }
    return value
}


override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    let ballRadius: CGFloat = 10
    destX = clamp(destX, min: ballRadius, max: frame.width - ballRadius)
    destY = clamp(destY, min: ballRadius, max: frame.height - ballRadius)

    let destXAction = SKAction.moveToX(destX, duration: 0.1)
    let destYAction = SKAction.moveToY(destY, duration: 0.1)
    self.circleNode.runAction(destXAction)
    self.circleNode.runAction(destYAction)
}
```

This will make it so the ball should never try to go outside the bounds of the screen. I would also suggest adding `circleNode.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true` so your collisions are more accurate.